# Codeigniter: passing data from view to controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my view code:

```
<p align="center"; style="font-size:22px">Database books</p>
        <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Book ID</th>
        <th>Book Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Author</th>
        <th>Publisher</th>
        <th>Pages</th>
        <th>Publication Date</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Genres</th>
        <th>User Rating</th>
        <th>Reviews</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
      </tr>
      <?php foreach($books as $book) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $book->book_id ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book->book_name ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book->description ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book->author ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book->publisher ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book->pages ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book->publication_date ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book->price ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book->status ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book->quantity ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book->genres ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book->user_rating ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $book->reviews ?></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/edit_data">Edit</a></td>
      </tr>
      <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

May i know how do i pass data from my view to my controller, as i would like to pass the information to my edit page. I am trying to search on passing variable using  anchor tag, however i am getting information on using GET and POST only are there any other ways?

Comment: why dont you want to use GET and POST?

Comment: I guess POST is fine, but was thinking are there any better ways of doing it

Comment: the way of design this kind of editing is that you only need to set a id to edit link , e.g. such as <?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/edit_data/1 where 1 is the id, then in the edit page you query the the record with id=1 again then display the values in fields.

Comment: so i will be passing the id from one view to another view directly skipping the controller?

Comment: no, you pass the id to edit_data function in your controller, where you get the record from the db, then return to your edit_data view. view in mvc is only for display record, all the logic behind should be on controller layer

Comment: <td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/edit_data">Edit</a></td> change it to <td><a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/edit_data/'.$book->book_id); ?>">Edit</a></td>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the href link to

```
href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/edit_data/<?php echo $book->book_id ?>"
```

Then you can get the book id on your controller function edit data

```
function edit_data($bookid) {

    //you can use $bookid to fetch data from db

}
```

Comment: Thank you everyone who helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

The above href link is right.

```
href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/edit_data/<?php echo $book->book_id ?>"
```

just add `$bookid = $this->uri->segment(3);` inside `function edit_data() {// do stuff here}` to retrieve book id from the href link.

```
function edit_data() {
   $bookid = $this->uri->segment(3);
    //retrieving book id
}
```